# В контроллерах повторяются процедуры

Tags: asp.net-mvc

В приложении asp.net mvc в нескольких контроллерах используется один и тот же код. Есть ли возможность вынести эти процедуры в какое-то общее для всех контроллеров пространство?

Comment: как вариант создать некий *сервисный слой* в котором будут содержаться *общие* методы/функции, и по необходимости использовать в нужных контроллерах

Comment: @Bald сервисный слой - это некий класс? Где он должен храниться?

Comment: да, храните где Вам будет удобно

Comment: @Bald спасибо, это похоже на то, что я хотел)

Comment: @Bald стоит оформить как ответ

Comment: @PashaPash я боюсь не смогу написать *хороший* ответ, а писать ответ состоящий из 2 строчек на такой сложный вопрос мне что то не хочется, может Вы бы смогли написать хороший ответ?

Comment: @Bald по-моему, двух строчек будет достаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы попробовал повторяющиеся функции/методы вынести в *сервисный слой*(класс в котором будут реализованы необходимые методы/функции), который подключал бы по необходимости в нужных контролерах и таким образом избавился от дублирования